# iOS - Setting first Screen after LaunchScreen

Tags: ios, xcode

Im new to iOS development coming from an Android background and im looking to set the first screen after the launch screen.

I believe the relevant code is

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
rootViewController = [UITabBarController new];
self.window.rootViewController = rootViewController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
[self setup];
```

The XIB file for the screen i want to set to first screen is called LoginView.xib

What do i need to do?

The boilerplate app im using is a mix of Swift and Objective C

Thanks

Comment: in MainStoryboard select controller you want be first and check "Initial controller", to do it in code you have to set ViewController identifier and instantiate it like this let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "YOUR_STORYBOARD_NAME", bundle: nil)
        window?.rootViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "identifier")

Comment: This is a pretty broad question... The code you are showing is instantiating a `UITabBarController` -- is that what you want? If so, you need to also instantiate the view controllers you want for the tabs... If you really just want to start with the `LoginView.xib`, it needs to be connected to a view controller, and *that* is what you want to set as the `.rootViewController`

Comment: DonMag That code is what is there now and i need to change i believe. Alexandr How do i open the MainStoryboard or check which Storyboard is set to main? Im just starting ios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to set the view controllers that should be handled by the tabbar controller. In your case, you need to instantiate the view controller that displays the view in `LoginView.xib` - I assume it is called `LoginViewController`:

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
rootViewController = [UITabBarController new];
LoginViewController *lvc = [[LoginViewController  alloc] init];
// SecondViewController *secondVC = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];
// ThirdViewController  *thirdVC = [[ThirdViewController alloc] init];
rootViewController.viewControllers = @[lvc /*, secondVC, thirdVC */ ]; 
self.window.rootViewController = rootViewController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
[self setup];
```

If you don't want a tab bar controller initally, then just use

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
rootViewController = [LoginViewController new];
self.window.rootViewController = rootViewController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
[self setup];
```

Comment: Why is there still a mention of the UITabBarController when i dont want that to be the homescreen anymore? Im basically adding a login screen to an existing app. The existing app homescreen is the tabbed screen.